# module interconnection interface design

Tags: python, python-2.7, design-patterns, interface

I want to have some simple interfaces for the users to connect some pre-defined modules (I'm free to modify them if I have to).
Each module has a few named inputs and outputs. 
One module may connect to a few modules.
A few modules can connect to a single module.

This is what I have in my mind so far:
Option 1:
Each module has "in" and "out" dictionary for input and output, and the connection is made through code like this:

```
a.out["out 1"].to(b.in["in 1"]) # connect a's "out 1" output to b's "in 1" input
a.out["out 2"].to(b.in["in 2"]) # connect a's "out 2" output to b's "in 2" input
```

But this looks quite tedious, so I came up with Option 2:

```
# connect a to b and c, then list which inputs connect to which outputs
a.to(b,{"out 1":"in 1",
        "out 2":"in 2"},
     c,{"out 4":"in 1",
        "out 3":"in 2"})
```

This seems to look better as it's clearer to me which modules are connected and also the mapping between their outputs and inputs are clearly listed.

I wonder if there is any room to improve the above, to clearly show:

- module level connections, e.g. module a connect to module b
- outputs and inputs connections
- simple and clear interface. By 'simple', I mean less typing; 'clear' means easy to understand. I understand that sometimes I can't have both in that case, 'clear' interface is preferable.

I'm not proficient in Python(2.7) so there might be some syntax or operator or data structure that I am not aware of but I may be able to take advantage for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run into this exact issue, the issue of being able to clearly describe directed graphs linearly. None are particularly pleasant... Personally, I believe showing how the sources and sinks (node inputs and outputs) connect is more important than showing which nodes are connected, because the relationship is more specific.

Of the two designs you listed I would recommend the first, since it is clearer. It shows exactly how each input and output connects. However, I would slightly augment your implementation. I would make the node class capable of creating new handles for inputs and outputs that are actual attributes in the object. Then use those handles when describing the graph and capturing traffic, etc. Making the inputs and outputs actual objects instead of labels means construction-time checking and the ability to generate better error messages. For example:

```
b = Node()
b.input("in1", "in2")  # this creates a new input object that is located in 'b' with the attribute name of the given string
b.output("out1")  # this could be in the constructor
c = Node(in=["in1", "in2"], out=["out1"])  # like so

# describe the connections
a.out1.to(b.in1)
a.out2.to(b.in2)
a.out3.to(c.in2)
a.out4.to(c.in1)
# maybe syntax like 'a.out3 >> c.in2' would be prettier?

module_graph_output = c.out1.capture()
# do stuff with the graph output
```

Additionally, the module definitions can be passed these output and input object handlers for the user as they implement the module logic.

All this aside, how you are going to run the module graph is the bigger issue. If I'm not intruding, what is the application of this?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I like the idea of using '>>' operator. But since the user of my code don't normally creates the I/O as they only use the pre-defined modules with known I/O. The reason that I want to use label style I/O instead of actual objects is that I need to distinguish the I/O members and other members. If I put them into a container (dictionary in this case), it's easier for the user to know where to find them, i.e. they won't mix up with I/O members and other members.

Comment: The application is to make a flow style processing library dealing with 2D data.

Comment: That was my problem as well. But instead of 2D data, my data was disassembly information. Each module in my system did different text analyses simultaneously; and it was flow-style. There are [batch-style data processing libraries](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/luigi), but that might not suit you. Considering your needs I'll make an edit to my answer.

Comment: @james Also, it is possible to use objects while still retaining textual labels by (ab)using `__getattr__`. This could lead to better-looking syntax and the ability to have a hook called which would register connections to the runtime. I assume in your implementation that a runtime will do the passing of messages between the modules and not the modules themselves (via message queues and calls to `push()` and `pop()` in the module code). And that goes back to what I said about this portion of the problem being designed around how the runtime will work.